# How to pass parameters from one controller to another in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, controller, parameter-passing

Can anyone tell me how to pass parameters to a function in another controller in cakephp?

Comment: Can you please provide more information about what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How are you calling that controller? If you're redirecting the user and want to pass some URL parameters (which will be passed to the controller action), just do this:

```
$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'foo', 'action' => 'bar', $myParam));
```

Comment: I'm calling the method by using 
$this->requestAction('/User/addToCart');
It is working fine without passing any value.
But now I want to send values to it. 
Is it possible in this case.

Comment: @Joe What about `$this->requestAction("/User/addToCart/$param");`? If that doesn't work, update your question with **more details**.